# Apache WordPress Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, apache, wordpress-плагины, contact-form7, httpd

Проблема многослойная :
1 основная проблема)  -не работает форма отправки Contact Form 7 валидацию в админке wp проходит, с виду все настройки верные. В настройках постфикса inet_interfaces = $myip. При нажатии send уходит со статусом 301, но ничего не отправляет

2) В связи с тем, что первую проблему решить не получается, - попытался включить дебаг мод:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

при этом в wp-contets/debug.log пусто, никаких ошибок не пишет (ручками создал файл debug.log). Накинул chown apache:apache, директория wp 755
В стандартной помойке /var/log/httpd/err* - тоже ничего связанного с ошибками.

Я бы с радостью докопался до истины, если бы не проблема с логами, которых нет, и не ясно как правильно включить, вынужден просить помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Не факт, что проблема в CF7. Поставьте плагин WP Mail SMTP для проверки, настройте его на отправку с Google или Yandex адреса, проверьте отправку его встроенными средствами. Если тестовое письмо уйдёт - должна работать и CF7.

Если по-прежнему не будет работать отправка с CF7 -  проблема в этом плагине (но я очень сомневаюсь).

Скорее всего, у вас или postfix настроен неверно, или нет SPF, DKIM, DMARC. А без этого на надёжную отправку писем с сервера рассчитывать не стоит.